# Database with diseases and symptoms?

Tags: symptoms, disease, data

Is there a database with diseases and symptoms?
I imagine something like being able input symptoms and getting a list of appropriate diseases?

Comment: They are sites that have "symptoms checkers." The may be misleading and disappointing, so do not take as an answer. You may get a better insight if you ask on some health forum.

Comment: There are, the only reliable ones are operated, maintained  and accessible by ONLY qualified medical professionals. If you want access to one I suggest you talk to your Doctor/GP about it.

Comment: Does anyone have specific recommendations for some sites that are easily accessible online to the public?

Comment: In addition to what @JJosaur suggested, those reliable websites/ specialised medical search engines are mostly not free of charge.

Answer (score 3):

There's an App call Ada. It's only available for iOS. It's an IA based bot that ask you about your symptoms and gives you a diagnostic. It was pretty accurate with some regular illnesses. It's much more advanced than a "symptoms checker", it can for example give you opinions based on statistical data. Also keeps record of your symptoms and dates, and ask you after if you are feeling better or worse or if you are cured.

[Ada - Personal Health Companion](https://ada.com/)

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing that does what you asked as a medical doctor would do, because a software is always a software.

Anyway a good reference (there should be also a function similar to the one you asked for) can be found on http://reference.medscape.com/

Answer (score 1):

There are quite some symptom checkers available - this one seems to perform well in benchmarks and allows free text input: https://www.symptoma.com/